# Did Obi-Wan ever reach out to Anakin after he became Vader?

Tags: star-wars

In the latest Dark Horse Star Wars comic, Obi-Wan's ghost starts talking to Vader, mostly messing with him, but it occurred to me.

Has any early Expanded Universe material had Obi-Wan reach out to Vader?

Comment: Definitely not definitive, but the "a presence I've not felt since..." line in ANH seems to imply that at the very least, he didn't have any contact since RotS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. During the period between *Revenge of the Sith* and *A New Hope* Obi-Wan was ensconced on Tatooine to keep an eye on Luke. While he had some contact with other fallen Jedi - notable the later Darth Krayt - he had none with Vader. There has also, as of June 2013 - I do not know the current comic series you're mentioning - never been a case of the two having contact via Force-ghost after Obi-Wan's death.